# Round list of decimal values with sum conditional by using VB.NET or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have table of decimal numbers which SUMs give integer numbers:

```
ID  Column1 Column2     Column3 Column4 SUM
1   1247.6  1163.0      1478.6  102.8   3992
2   501.2   203.4       205.1   155.3   1065
3   105.1   257.8       247.7   1025.4  1636
4   247.0   887.4       745.2   476.4   2356
```

When I round these number their sum get change and it usually become SUM +/- 1, It occurs because of rounding.

```
ID  Column1 Column2     Column3 Column4 SUM SUMofRounded
1   1248    1163        1479    103     3992    3993
2   501      203        205     155     1065    1064
3   105      258        248    1025     1636    1636
4   247      887        745     476     2356    2355
```

How can I round these decimal numbers to integers with condition that the SUM stay same. I would prefer solution in SQL Server or VB.NET.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you sum the numbers first and then round off the sum. Even if you want to round off individual columns, use the actual values to find sum and then round off it

Comment: Sum of actual values is already integer.

Comment: If actual values are integers, then only sum would be integer, but in your example actual values are not integers. See Brian Presserler's answer. It is the same what I said above

Comment: It could be worse. 1.4 + 1.4 + 1.4 + 1.4 = 5.6 rounded = 6. Unless your sum is based on the integer value, there's not much you can do.

Comment: SUM column in first table gives sum values SUM(Column1 + Column2 + Column3 + Column4) and it is always integer. Data are set to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem now.  You are dissatisfied that the sum of the values individually rounded do not sum up to the rounded value of the total.

```
Round(Column1 + Column2 + Column3 + Column4, 0) <> Round(Column1, 0) + round(Column2)...
```

So you want to modify some of the rounded values so that they sum up to the rounded total.  In order to do that, you would have to distribute the rounding error in some way to the individual columns.  If you don't care how it's distributed... then you could just take all the round error and add it to just any one of the other columns.  Example:

```
select round(Column1,0) Column1,
    round(Column2,0) Column2,
    round(Column3,0) Column3,
    round(Column4,0) + round(Column1+Column2+Column3+Column4, 0) - (round(Column1,0)+round(Column2,0)+round(Column3,0)+round(Column4,0)) Column4,
    round(Column1+Column2+Column3+Column4, 0) SumTotal
from #Temp
```

If you care about how it's distributed... then you're going to have to specify.

Comment: No what is already done is SELECT ROUND(Column1,0) + Round(Column2,0) + Round(Column3,0) + Round(Column4,0) FROM Table

Comment: No, values give integer number SUM(Column1 + Column2 + Column3 + Column4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FLOOR function to achieve the same. Something like this:-

```
SELECT FLOOR(1247.6) = 1247
```

Comment: This might be misleading.  The FLOOR function simply truncates the decimal part.  Round will increment the integer part if the decimal part is above 0.5.

Comment: @BrianPressler, After your comment only, i am able to understand the problem of the user. Point accepted.